# How to upgrade SQL Server 2014 Express edition to developer edition

Tags: sql-server-2014

SQL Server 2014 Express edition is installed on my laptop. I downloaded the `.ISO` file for the Developer edition from this link: https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=SQL%20Server%202014%20with%20Service%20Pack%201

Is it possible to upgrade the existing SQL Server Express edition to Developer edition? Or do I have to install a separate instance of Developer edition?

Comment: You cannot really "upgrade" an existing installation - just install Developer edition as a separate instance. Since you have **Express**; this is most likely installed as the `.\SQLEXPRESS` instance - so you can even install the Developer edition as the *default, unnamed* instance that can be accessed by specifying `.`, `(local)`, or `YourPcName` as the server/instance name

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really "upgrade" an existing SQL Server instance.

I'd recommend to just install the Developer Edition as a separate instance.

Since you have SQL Server Express, this is most likely installed as the `.\SQLEXPRESS` instance - so you can probably install the Developer edition as the *default, unnamed instance* that can be accessed by specifying `.`, `(local)`, or `YourPcName` as the server/instance name side-by-side with your Express instance.

If you need to move databases to the new instance, the easiest way is to just simply backup from the Express instance into a `.bak` file, and then restoring that to the Developer edition instance.